# Raspberry Pi Tkinter via shh and xming

Tags: python-3.x, ssh, tkinter, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to run a Tkinter script from a raspberry, via an ssh client and xming. Once I've logged into the pi via shh I use the command:

```
gksudo python3 home/pi/PythonScripts/TkinterTest.py
```

This is the error that is given on my PC:

```
(gksudo:2700): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

and a different error on my laptop running the same software:

```
(gksudo:3227): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_str_has_prefix: assertion 'str != NULL' failed
```

I have tried to change the display with the command:

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

But this had no effect on the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First of all be sure that **the X forwarding** is actived on your raspberry, you can check that in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`: `X11Forwarding yes`
2. `ssh -X username@<raspberry>` (-X flag for the X11 forwarding)
3. Run your script : `(su) python /path/to/script.py`

Sometimes when you try to run program via sudo you can have some error, you need to check the permissions of .Xauthority file

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I know this Question is 3 years old. But my search landed me here. So just answering the question

```
sudo cp ~pi/.Xauthority ~root/
```

This just copies the X11 authority file directly to root without the xauth command management. This will make all active user pi X11 connections available for use by root without having to sort through and find the correct one.

P.S : I'm just copy pasting, credit goes to [this answer in this forum](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=26934&p=242112&hilit=tkinter+display#p242853)