# Why am I not able to run Tkinter simple test?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, raspberry-pi3

I'm testing tkinter GUI via ssh on Raspberri pi 3

Python code:

```
python3
>> import tkinter
>> tkinter._test()
```

and I am getting [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x11dH.png) error.

Is this something because I'm using SSH?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, tkinter need to be launch from a graphic environment. If you want to do it in remote you should use vnc.

Comment: So if I perform same task in raspbian OS, will it work fine?

Comment: You can do it with ssh if you're on machine that supports X11 and are connecting to a machine that supports X11, and using you are using X11 forwarding.

Comment: @BryanOakley What is X11? I'm sorry I'm completely new to all this.

Comment: @Hiranya: it is the windowing system for linux and unix-like operating systems. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System

Comment: Yes it should work in raspbianOS. For X11 forwarding on mac install [XQuartz](https://www.xquartz.org/) or windows take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29593245/raspberry-pi-tkinter-via-shh-and-xming). Then `ssh -X pi@raspberrypi` and try again.